I am getting a DU anomaly(PMD) in my code. I am not sure how to fix this
I have to iterate over the request and create a new Entity List request which I can use in saveAll() method of JPA repository
I am getting DU anomaly
Error I am encountering is from PMD.

DU - Anomaly: A recently defined variable is undefined. These anomalies may appear in normal source text.

Map<Integer, AlertHeader> alertHeaderMap = findAllAlertRecords(lockAlertRequest);

List<AlertHeader> alertHeaderRequestToUpdate = lockAlertRequest.stream()
        .map(request -> {
            AlertHeader alertHeader = alertHeaderMap.get(request.getAlertId());
            alertValidatorUtil.validateRecordNotFound(alertHeader, request);
            alertValidatorUtil.validateUnauthorizedLock(alertHeader, request);
            alertHeader.setStatus(AlertStatus.valueOf(request.getStatus()));
            alertHeader.setExpediteEmployeeId(request.getExpediteEmployeeId());
            alertHeader.setExpdLockDateTime(parseDateTime(request.getExpediteLockDateTime()));
            return alertHeader;
        })
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

alertHeaderRepository.saveAll(alertHeaderRequestToUpdate);

If am using this code snippet I am not getting any error not able to understand the real cause here.
lockAlertRequest.forEach(request -> { AlertHeader alertHeader = alertHeaderMap.get(request.getAlertId()); alertValidatorUtil.validateRecordNotFound(alertHeader, request); alertValidatorUtil.validateUnauthorizedLock(alertHeader, request); alertHeader.setStatus(AlertStatus.valueOf(request.getStatus())); alertHeader.setExpediteEmployeeId(request.getExpediteEmployeeId()); alertHeader.setExpdLockDateTime(parseDateTime(request.getExpediteLockDateTime())); alertHeaderRequestToUpdate.add(alertHeader); });


The warning is a false positive that can be ignored / suppressed.
Having said that, you seem to be using a VERY OLD version of PMD. The rule that produces this warning (DataflowAnomalyAnalysis) has been deprecated since PMD 6.27.0 (August 2020), and completely removed in PMD 7.0.0.
A better (more accurate) rule named UnusedAssignment has been available since PMD 6.26.0 (July 2020).
My best advice is to update to PMD 7.2.0, or at the very least to 6.55.0 if you can't / don't want to deal with upgrading from PMD 6 to 7.

I'm assuming that error message is coming from PMD.  You should tell us these things.
When I googled that message, the first search result is this PMD issue: https://github.com/pmd/pmd/issues/1304.  The response to the issue is saying that these are often false positives.  It says:

Unfortunately, this rule is by far the poorest in PMD. The data flow codebase has long been outdated, and has little or no understanding of any Java construct introduced in Java 5 or later (for-each-loops, try-with-resources, lambdas...), so these kind of false positives are not uncommon.
We want to revamp it at some point, but so far such an effort is unscheduled. It may be a good GSoC project candidate for 2019.

GSoC was Google Summer of Code, but my guess is that this issue wasn't addressed then ... or since then.

You apparently didn't include all of the error information in your post.  It should have mentioned which variable the DU anomaly is for.  But you are certainly using post-Java 5 constructs there.

error I am encountering is alertHeaderRequestToUpdate. And yes this is a PMD error message sorry i thought it would be generic.
Also what should I do? If am going with normal forEach approach just adding these request to a list I don't get this error.

Don't put this in comments.  Edit the question.

Then I will update my answer.  (But not now because I'm going to bed.)

Sure, I have updated. @Stephen C
